# Secure streams in java

Tags: java, stream

What is the best way to secure streams in java? I have to stream audio files which needs authentication before it can be accessed

Comment: What do you mean by secure? Transmitting over a SSL socket would be "secure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at secure sockets layer (SSL or HTTPS) as TJR said.  When you are using SSL, the transmissions are secured, so the next step is to authenticate over that secure transmission if you want to make sure the user is someone you know.  [This article](http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php) might get you started.